# Unable to invoke Browser from Jenkins Job for Protractor Code (Note: Jenkins is set-up through Docker Image)

Tags: docker, jenkins, protractor, webdriver

Mentioning the steps that I have followed and the problem that I am facing:

I have pulled jenkins image through below docker command

```
docker pull jenkins/jenkins:lts
```

Jenkins is up, Git integration also seems fine as it clones the git repo. The only folder which does not get cloned is webdriver-manager.

I have used below commands in the Jenkins Job 'Execute Shell' (Note I have tried both with g and without g)

```
npm install -g protractor
npm install -g chromedriver
webdriver-manager update
protractor conf.js
```

I get below message in the console

```
[08:31:26] I/update - chromedriver: unzipping chromedriver_88.0.4324.96.zip
[08:31:26] I/update - chromedriver: setting permissions to 0755 for /var/jenkins_home/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/NodeJS/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_88.0.4324.96
```

which shows that it has extracted chormedriver in this folder "node_modules/protractor/node_modules" but when I go there in workspace it is not present.

I get below console error after execution

```
protractor conf.js
[08:31:29] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[08:31:29] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...
[08:31:29] E/runner - Unable to start a WebDriver session.
[08:31:29] E/launcher - Error: Error: Server terminated early with status 127
    at /var/jenkins_home/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/NodeJS/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/remote/index.js:252:52
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:94:5)
[08:31:29] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 100
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
```

**Problem statement** Unable to invoke the browser so test execution gets failed.

**Current Solutions that I have read** - It suggests to run in headless mode, but I want to run it in browser where I can see the execution, **I don't want to run headless**

Please help, thanks

Comment: confirm your jenkins docker install headfull Chrome browser, secondly you need run protractor test cmd through approach which has GUI session not tty session.  I'm not sure i remember exactly, use xterm linux cmd too run protractor test.

Comment: Hi @yong ,thanks for responding on this thread. I am new in Docker and Protractor both. I could not follow the point for headfull Chrome browser. I could not found any relevant article for that, is there a good link that you can suggest, I will try to implement that.
Also for the 2nd point regarding running protractor through GUI session, do I need to change the way I am executing it in the Jenkins Shell command ? or are you suggesting something else.

thanks for the response !

Comment: Headful here means run browser as normal, we can see the browser.  you need confirm chrome installed on machine/image where test script run.

Comment: Hi @yong, to resolve it, I created a yml file for docker compose but still getting same error. docker file is below

version: '3'

services:

        jenkins:
                image: jenkins/jenkins:lts
                ports:
                - 6060:8080
                - 50000:50000

        chrome:
                image: browserless/chrome 

Tried different chrome images, this one too 'selenium/standalone-chrome'

Now thinking to create a docker file with Jenkins & Chrome both, will it be a good idea to try?
If there are any suggestions for this file,please let me know.Thanks